# How do I turn an LED on in a circuit if an input voltage is between -2V and 2V

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I am looking to build a circuit with an LED that is on when the input voltage is between +-2V and off otherwise. I have +-5V available for the rails.

Comment: Can you fix your numbers so this question makes sense ? Also please list whatever rail voltages you have available.

Comment: The numbers above are just examples.  I have +-5V available for the rails.  I am just looking to build a circuit with an LED that is on when the input voltage is between  +-2V and off otherwise.

Comment: @ALec is it ±2 V or ±2 mV?

Comment: @HarrySvensson ±2 V

Comment: YOu need a range comparator, a modified version of this circuit https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=HqE4vKiy&id=2ED3FFA3E40E2BBC9D6BE9D23311C9D6CEC8D773&thid=OIP.HqE4vKiyt5z5c-nQ-sUp7wEsEs&q=range+comparitor&simid=608037998029309637&selectedIndex=0&ajaxhist=0 Replace +12V with +5V and ground with -5V and pick the resistors you need to set the levels. Power the comparitors with +-5V

Comment: No response to clarify how +/- 2 Volts is *driving* this LED off of +/- 5 volt rails. VTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eg. Using [LM393](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393-n.pdf) dual comparator- probably the least expensive solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Ug94.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The comparators are open-collector outputs that can sink at least 4mA. When the input exceeds either limit (set by the divider R1/R2/R4 from the supply voltages) the relevant comparator output goes low, shunting the current through R3 away from the LED and turning it off.

Comment: +1 I might tie the top of a smaller R3 to ground instead though.

Comment: @Trevor yup saves a bit of power.

Answer (score 1):

First you rectify it, then you use a [Schmitt trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger#Inverting_Schmitt_trigger) (inverting in this case), and then you're done.

Here's the schematic I came up with.

[image]

The only change you have to do on your part is to change the negative voltage supply to the op-amps to ground. It doesn't really matter that the supply to the left op-amp is ±5 V, but on the right op-amp. The Schmitt trigger, it matters.

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+0.44816890703380646+62+1+50%0AR+-544+80+-592+80+0+3+400+4+0+0+0.5%0Aa+-432+128+-336+128+0+15+0+1000000+2.622285640377078+0%0Aw+-432+80+-432+112+0%0Ag+-432+144+-432+160+0%0Ad+-336+128+-288+128+1+0.805904783%0Ar+-432+80+-288+80+0+10000%0Ar+-496+80+-432+80+0+10000%0Aw+-288+80+-288+96+2%0Aa+-288+144+-192+144+0+5+0+1000000+2.6205712875766083+1.9999875883260145%0Aw+-192+144+-144+144+0%0Aw+-288+160+-288+224+2%0Ar+-240+224+-192+224+0+100000%0Aw+-192+224+-192+144+0%0Ar+-336+176+-336+224+0+50000%0AR+-336+176+-336+160+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-288+224+-240+224+0%0Ag+-336+272+-336+288+0%0Ar+-336+272+-336+224+0+50000%0Aw+-288+96+-288+128+0%0Aw+-336+224+-288+224+0%0AM+-144+144+-112+144+0+2.5%0Aw+-544+80+-496+80+2%0Ax+-559+48+-498+51+4+24+input%0Ax+-346+50+-224+53+4+24+abs(input)%0Ax+-292+261+-169+264+4+24+hysteresis%0Ax+-145+122+-67+125+4+24+output%0Ao+21+1+0+4098+10.04621530110757+0.0004+0+3+21+3+20+0%0Ao+7+1+0+4098+5+0.0015625+0+2+7+3%0A) if you want to simulate it in your browser.

If you however cannot change the negative voltage supply to the op-amps then you will have to change the values of the resistors so it's more like [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%200.44816890703380646%2062%201%2050%0AR%2032%2096%20-16%2096%200%203%20400%204%200%200%200.5%0Aa%20144%20144%20240%20144%200%205%20-5%201000000%20-0.00003622095348722254%200%0Aw%20144%2096%20144%20128%200%0Ag%20144%20160%20144%20176%200%0Ad%20240%20144%20288%20144%201%200.805904783%0Ar%20144%2096%20288%2096%200%2010000%0Ar%2080%2096%20144%2096%200%2010000%0Aw%20288%2096%20288%20112%202%0Aa%20288%20160%20384%20160%200%205%20-5%201000000%203.2319275667354246%201.9999876811010804%0Aw%20384%20160%20432%20160%200%0Aw%20288%20176%20288%20240%202%0Ar%20336%20240%20384%20240%200%20200000%0Aw%20384%20240%20384%20160%200%0Ar%20240%20192%20240%20240%200%2040000%0AR%20240%20192%20240%20176%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20288%20240%20336%20240%200%0Ag%20240%20288%20240%20304%200%0Ar%20240%20288%20240%20240%200%2050000%0Aw%20288%20112%20288%20144%200%0Aw%20240%20240%20288%20240%200%0AM%20432%20160%20464%20160%200%202.5%0Aw%2032%2096%2080%2096%202%0Ax%2017%2064%2078%2067%204%2024%20input%0Ax%20230%2066%20352%2069%204%2024%20abs(input)%0Ax%20284%20277%20407%20280%204%2024%20hysteresis%0Ax%20431%20138%20509%20141%204%2024%20output%0Ao%2021%201%200%204098%2010.04621530110757%200.0004%200%203%2021%203%2020%200%0Ao%207%201%200%204098%205%200.0015625%200%202%207%203%0A).

---

How did I come up with the values for the resistors?

Well I started with 50 kΩ for the pull-down and then just fiddled with the values in the simulator until I saw values that "made sense".

If I wanted to be *perfect*, such as solving answers for some exam, then I'd set up algebraic equations such as "if output is 5 V, there's some feed back resistor here and a pull-up resistor there and pull-down resistor = 50 kΩ there, what do the resistances have to be if I want to get 2 V?, okay. And if output is -5 V, then what?" Then I plug the equations in to each other and retrieve my values.

Two equations and two unknown resistor values.

---

I went for your "Example" text, thinking that it was your actual goal. If it isn't then shame on you and shame on me.

Comment: Isn't that only a half wave rectifier?

Comment: @Trevor Hmm, that may be the correct term but misleading. Because if the input is negative then the op-amp will output (-input) and if input is positive then op-amp won't do anything and the output will be (input). In **both cases** you get a positive value at the output. So... "full wave rectifier".... But yeah, I don't care/mind really, *I* will call it *full wave rectifier*. Because that is how the wave look afterwards. This answer is probably wrong anyways because the question differed from his/hers own example (I think). Which is very strange.

Comment: Yup. its hard to tell if this is a dc input level or he wants to detect <2V pk-pk..